# No "NOT NULL" and "UNIQUE" constraint on Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

While playing with the **Room Persistence Library** I came to know that there is no methodology to set a data class field with NOT NULL and also UNIQUE constraints. whether SQLite supports those constraints. Isn't it a problem to migrate old database where those constraints are used? Can anyone give a suggestion for this issue?

Comment: unique constraint is  supported, check Indices and uniqueness , https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> I came to know that there is no methodology to set a data class field with NOT NULL and also UNIQUE constraints

A `@NonNull` annotation on an `@Entity` field will cause that field's column to have `NOT NULL` applied to it.

`unique=true` on an `@Index` will enforce a uniqueness constraint (e.g., `@Entity(indices={@Index(value="something", unique=true)}`). However, you are correct that a plain `UNIQUE` constraint on a column, other than via an index, is not supported.

> Isn't it a problem to migrate old database where those constraints are used?

Room is not designed to support existing database structures, particularly in the now-current `alpha` state. Over time, I would expect Room to support a higher percentage of SQLite features, though I will be stunned if it ever reaches 100%.

Comment: Thank you for knowing so much about the Room library. I have so many questions and it's always your answers where I get the solutions :D

Comment: I am little bit confused. Can you please clarify from which pacage `@NonNull` I need to import? 
`android.support.annotation`
or `javax.annotation` ?

Comment: @Ifta: I would use the `android.support.annotation` one, though hopefully the Room annotation processor checks for both.

Comment: koltin version `@Entity(tableName = "some_table", indices = [
    Index(value = ["some_field"], unique = true)
])`

Answer (score 8):

Complementary answer about `NOT NULL` for those using Kotlin:

please note that marking a type as non optional will automatically make it not null (and an optional type will not do that).

You can check it in the schema generated by room with `@Database(exportSchema = true)` on your database.

For example I have something like that:

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class Message (
        @PrimaryKey
        val messageId: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
        val date: Date = Date(),
        val receivedDate: Date? = null
)
```

And in the generated schema I can read:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`messageId` TEXT NOT NULL, `date` INTEGER NOT NULL, `receivedDate` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`messageId`))"
```

(Note: the Date type is here an `Int` and the UUID a string due to converters I use elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple item that is to be marked unique & based on that you want to insert in db then you can use composite primary key.

For Not null, Room has provided "@NonNull" annotation that is added over the field that cannot be null.

In the below mentioned eg. roll number is unique in each class but 2 different class can have same roll number. So we can use class & rollNumber as composite primary key & insert in db uniquely.
Example:

```
    @Entity(primaryKeys = {"rollNumber", "class"})   
    class Student {
       @NonNull
        private int rollNumber;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int class;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

for a null able field you can use wrapper primitive type java. for example use Integer instance int in your Room Table. 
as in  [wrapper primitive type java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class)  this can bee null but primitive type class cant bee null. and in generation of this SQL code for primitive field that use notNull=true but when use Integer in generayion SQL code use notNull=false